# "Saved Password Editor" in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

Do we have ["Saved Password Editor"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/saved-password-editor/) in chrome?

If no how can I manage it for sites which supress password remember options ?

I am using chrome Version 26.0.1410.63

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Going to the address chrome://settings/passwords/ should allow you to manage your saved passwords. however, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "sites which suppress password remember options", so maybe that will not resolve your issue.